# Use some basic PHP in parse.com static content hosting

Tags: php, parse-platform

I want to be able to run some PHP code in my mostly static webpage, my `Parse` project looks like this:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── cloud
│   └── main.js
├── config
│   └── global.json
└── public
    ├── confirmation.html
    ├── contact.php
    ├── contactsettings.php
    ├── css
    ├── experiencias
    ├── fonts
    ├── img
    ├── index.html
    ├── js
    ├── redirect.html
    ├── subscribe.php
    └── thanks.html
```

So as you can see, I have some PHP code to run, yet when trying to, `Parse` gives me the following error:

> Page not found
>
> This Parse App does not have a page at the requested URL.

Comment: Parse.com does not support PHP, but they have Cloud Code: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide

Comment: @nathancahill are you sure? https://parse.com/products/php

Comment: That's the PHP SDK, not a PHP stack on their static hosting service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in a comment by @nathancahill, Parse.com **STATIC** webhosting does not support PHP code.

PHP code is dynamic and not static content.

To host a dynamic website on Parse, you can use [Cloud Code](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide) or [Express](http://expressjs.com/).

Read more here: https://parse.com/docs/hosting_guide#webapp